# preg_match_all for table having case sensitive code

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I was trying to extract railway tickets data for internal use.

Total data looks like [this table](http://pastebin.com/zJrvq95H).

I have extracted every `<td>` content with `preg_match_all` condition but I cannot extract coach position as seen in this screenshot [image]

I have tried code like below :

```
<?php
    $result='tables code over here which you can find in pastebin link';
    preg_match_all('/<TD class="table_border_both"><b>(.*)<\/b><\/TD>/s',$result,$matches);
    var_dump($matches);
?>
```

I get rubbish output like:

1. [image]
2. [image]

Comment: Try the non-greedy `.*?` match instead of the greedy `.*`. The latter will try to match as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following regular Expression:

```
$re = "/<TD class=\"table_border_both\"><b>([0-9][0-9])\n<\/b><\/TD>/"; 
$str = "<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"1\" class=\"table_border\">\n\n<tr>\n<td colspan=\"9\" class=\"heading_table_top\">Journey Details</td>\n</tr>\n<TR class=\"heading_table\">\n<td width=\"11%\">Train Number</Td>\n<td width=\"16%\">Train Name</td>\n<td width=\"18%\">Boarding Date <br>(DD-MM-YYYY)</td>\n<td width=\"7%\">From</Td>\n<td width=\"7%\">To</Td>\n<td width=\"14%\">Reserved Upto</Td>\n<td width=\"21%\">Boarding Point</Td>\n<td width=\"6%\">Class</Td>\n</TR>\n<TR>\n<TD class=\"table_border_both\">*12559</TD>\n<TD class=\"table_border_both\">SHIV GANGA EXP </TD>\n<TD class=\"table_border_both\"> 5- 7-2014</TD>\n<TD class=\"table_border_both\">BSB </TD>\n<TD class=\"table_border_both\">NDLS</TD>\n<TD class=\"table_border_both\">NDLS</TD>\n<TD class=\"table_border_both\">BSB </TD>\n<TD class=\"table_border_both\"> SL</TD>\n</TR>\n</table>\n<TABLE width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"1\" class=\"table_border\" id=\"center_table\" >\n\n<TR>\n<td width=\"25%\" class=\"heading_table_top\">S. No.</td>\n<td width=\"45%\" class=\"heading_table_top\">Booking Status <br /> (Coach No , Berth No., Quota)</td>\n<td width=\"30%\" class=\"heading_table_top\">* Current Status <br />(Coach No , Berth No.)</td>\n<td width=\"30%\" class=\"heading_table_top\">Coach Position</td>\n</TR>\n<TR>\n<TD class=\"table_border_both\"><B>Passenger 1</B></TD>\n<TD class=\"table_border_both\"><B>S1  , 33,CK    </B></TD>\n<TD class=\"table_border_both\"><B>S1  , 33</B></TD>\n<TD class=\"table_border_both\"><b>11\n</b></TD>\n</TR>\n<TR>\n<TD class=\"table_border_both\"><B>Passenger 2</B></TD>\n<TD class=\"table_border_both\"><B>S1  , 34,CK    </B></TD>\n<TD class=\"table_border_both\"><B>S1  , 34</B></TD>\n<TD class=\"table_border_both\"><b>11\n</b></TD>\n</TR>\n<TR>\n<TD class=\"table_border_both\"><B>Passenger 3</B></TD>\n<TD class=\"table_border_both\"><B>S1  , 36,CK    </B></TD>\n<TD class=\"table_border_both\"><B>S1  , 36</B></TD>\n<TD class=\"table_border_both\"><b>11\n</b></TD>\n</TR>\n<TR>\n<TD class=\"table_border_both\"><B>Passenger 4</B></TD>\n<TD class=\"table_border_both\"><B>S1  , 37,CK    </B></TD>\n<TD class=\"table_border_both\"><B>S1  , 37</B></TD>\n<TD class=\"table_border_both\"><b>11\n</b></TD>\n</TR>\n<TR>\n<td class=\"heading_table_top\">Charting Status</td>\n<TD colspan=\"3\" align=\"middle\" valign=\"middle\" class=\"table_border_both\">   CHART PREPARED   </TD>\n</TR>\n<TR>\n<td colspan=\"4\"><font color=\"#1219e8\" size=\"1\"><b> * Please Note that in case the Final Charts have not been prepared, the Current Status might upgrade/downgrade at a later stage.</font></b></Td>\n</TR>\n</table>"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Most useful website for regex: http://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
$regexp = '/<td class="table_border_both"><b>(.*)\s*<\/b><\/td>/gi';
```

You have line break in "Coach position" `<td>` and you forgot to mention it in regexp.
And it is better to use `\s*` so if you have there spaces or line brakes it won't fail.

---

You know that you have 4 columns, thus the result from regexp will have further transformations:

```
$data = array_chunk($matches, 4); // split up the matches by rows
```

And you have already ready rows ... few more lines and you have more than you need:

```
$data = array_map(function (array $row) {
    return array_combine(['snum', 'status_book', 'status_cur', 'position'], $row);
}, $data); // assign each column in the row it's name
```

---

If we combine all the code, it will probably look like this:

```
$data = array_map(function (array $row) {
    return array_combine(['snum', 'status_book', 'status_cur', 'position'], $row);
}, array_chunk($matches, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Usage of `\s+` is needed because there are some spaces in rows, otherwise it won't be matched

```
$data = file_get_contents("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=zJrvq95H");
preg_match_all("#<b>([0-9]{0,})\s+<\/b>#", $data, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 11
    [1] => 11
    [2] => 11
    [3] => 11
)
```